# Calculated Column Based on Start and End Dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column

I'm trying to create a calculated column for a list that tracks personnel travelling.

There are two date columns in the list, one for their **departure date** and one for their **return date**.

I want a calculated column to identify their current status. Basically if neither date has passed I'd like it to say "*Pending*", if the departure date has passed but not the return date then "*Abroad*", if both dates have passed then "*Complete*".

I tried the below formula but keeping getting a syntax error. Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
=IF(AND([Departure Date] > NOW(), [Return Date] > NOW()), "Pending",
    IF(AND([Departure Date] <= NOW(), [Return Date] >= NOW()), "Abroad",
        IF(AND([Departure Date] < NOW(), [Return Date] < NOW()), "Complete", "")
    )
)
```

Comment: What regional settings are you using in your SPO-site? Sometime's it as simple as replacing all the commas with a semicolon.

Comment: I did try that, but still received the syntax error

Comment: Do the date columns allowing time to be set or dates only? What are your site regional settings (siteadress + /_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx) ?

Comment: Date columns are date only. Not sure what you mean by regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

The formula works for me (using semicolon ";" instead of comma ",").

```
=IF(AND([Departure Date] > NOW(); [Return Date] > NOW()); "Pending";
    IF(AND([Departure Date] <= NOW(); [Return Date] >= NOW()); "Abroad";
        IF(AND([Departure Date] < NOW(); [Return Date] < NOW()); "Complete"; "")
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Still getting the same error. I noticed you add an extra parenthesis after NOW before each of the text statements. I added those and still didn't work either.

Comment: Your calculated column - what type of data are it set to return? Single line of text?

Comment: Yes, single line of text

Answer (score 0):

I tested your formula and it works fine for me here. I have my date and result columns set up as follows.
[image]

[image]

[image]

If the problem persists, then you can try:

1.Whether all SharePoint lists have the same problem? You could create a new SharePoint list to check.

2.You could try to clear browser cache then restart it.

3.Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same error occurs.